# Running ‘heroku run:detached’ programmatically. How exactly?

Tags: heroku

I've tried googling and stackoverflowing this and all I get is links back to the API reference or examples of scaling dynos, which is not what I want.

`heroku run:detached` is great as it just spins up a dyno with your app, runs whatever you want, then spins down the dyno.

How do I achieve the exact same things but using the **Heroku Platform AP**I?

I've seen people mention you have to use the `Dyno` endpoint on the API, but how? Can someone offer an exact example of how I would run the following from the API?

```
$ heroku run:detached --size 2x rake my_task.rb
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the platform API to to this, and create a dyno.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-create

By sending a `POST` request to `/apps/your_app_name/dynos` with the following parameters:

- `command`, the command you wich to run.
- `attach`, set it to false.

This will create a one-off dyno and detach it.
This is what the toolbelt does when you run the `run:detached` command. You can see how it works here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/01cd753570cb62b917843112fb29d1cdd43ba335/lib/heroku/command/run.rb#L65

Comment: thanks! I guess it's not clear from the API that this will also spin down the dyno. So 'create' also takes care of destroying that dyno afterwards? When you say 'command' do you mean 'run rake my_task.rb' that's what I send? It would be super helpful if you could provide just an example of the API call?

Comment: actually just took a closer look at the link you provided. So I don't need to provide 'run' in the command parameter or I do? It's not very clear...?

Comment: And yes, one-off dynos are stopped once the process finishes working. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos